# Extracting parts of a string based on substrings in a dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, partition, strip

I am trying to extract some NBA data, but my dataframe has a column where all of the statistics are in one string separated by spaces in a Stats column as shown: eg. 29pt 15rb 3as 1bl ...etc. I want to extract the values of each statistic so that I have a column for points, rebounds, assist, blocks, etc. The issue I am running into is some rows might not contain every statistic. For example, if a player did not get any assists, their value in the Stats column could look like this: 14pt 3rb 2bl. I am having trouble extracting the values I need for each statistic, especially if the statistic doesn't exist for that player. I have tried to split the string so that its values are placed into a list, and this was promising, but I still cannot figure out how to get the values for each statistic if that statistic even exists for that player. Any recommendations, ideas, or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

SM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can step through this using [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to extract the values (regex explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/dgwdN7/1)), then convert that to a `dict` that we make back into a DataFrame that has the statistic as the column label and values.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(["29pt 15rb 3as 1bl", "14pt 3rb 2bl"])
>>> s
# 0    29pt 15rb 3as 1bl
# 1         14pt 3rb 2bl
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    s.str.findall(r"(\d+)(\w+)")
    .apply(lambda y: {k: v for v, k in y})
    .to_list()
)
>>> df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
>>> df
#    pt  rb   as  bl
# 0  29  15  3.0   1
# 1  14   3  NaN   2
```

This DataFrame can then be merged onto your original one matching on index.

---

`s.str.findall(r"(\d+)(\w+)")`

This line applies the regex `r"(\d+)(\w+)"` which defines two capture groups (the parentheses `()`). The first capture group looks for numbers (`\d+`), and the second capture group looks for word characters (`\w+`, equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`<sup>†</sup>). Using `findall` returns a list of tuples e.g

```
"29pt 15rb 3as 1bl" => [('29', 'pt'), ('15', 'rb'), ('3', 'as'), ('1', 'bl')]
```

Next, `.apply(lambda y: {k: v for v, k in y})` is chained on which applies the `lambda` function over each row. This function converts the list of tuples into a dictionary where the keys are the second element from the tuples above (pt, rb, ...) and the values are the numbers.

```
[('29', 'pt'), ('15', 'rb'), ('3', 'as'), ('1', 'bl')]
# becomes
{'pt': '29', 'rb': '15', 'as': '3', 'bl': '1'}
```

Finally, `.to_list()` converts our `pd.Series` into a list of dict, which we can use to create a DataFrame that is mergeable, with the original.

---

† As `\w+` is a greedy token that matches any letter, digit, or underscore it maybe better to use `[a-zA-Z]+` instead, which will only match letters.

Comment: Wow, this is incredible. Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this for hours, and your code works. I am having trouble following the findall function and the lambda function. Is it possible to explain what each of these functions is doing with in reference to the syntax used?

Comment: @StevenMiller Try executing each part of the function chain and examine the output individually. Start with `s.str.findall(r"(\d+)(\w+)")` then add the `apply(lambda ...)`. For me the magic happens in the `findall()` with the regex capturing groups.

Comment: @StevenMiller I've added some explanation, let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines?

```py
def parse_stat(stat):
    """takes 29pt and returns (int stat_value, str stat) as (29, "pt")"""
    i = 0
    while i < len(stat) and stat[i].isdigit():
        i += 1
    return int(stat[:i]), stat[i:]

def parse(string):
    substrings = string.split(' ')
    stats = {}
    for sub in substrings:
        val, stat = parse_stat(sub)
        stats[stat] = val
    return stats


if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = "9pt 15rb 3as 1bl"
    result = parse(string)
    print(result)
    print(result.get("pt", 0))
    print(result.get("fake", 0))
```

```
In: "9pt 15rb 3as 1bl"
Out: {'pt': 9, 'rb': 15, 'as': 3, 'bl': 1}
In: result.get("pt", 0)
Out: 9
In: result.get("fake", 0)
Out: 0
```